# npm + Gulp cannot find module gulp

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, gulp, angular-seed

I have a problem with my angular2-seed project. Executing "npm install" throws the following error:

```
          throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
                ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (2688)
gulpfile.ts (1,23): Cannot find module 'gulp'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (2,23): Cannot find module 'gulp-util'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (3,30): Cannot find module 'run-sequence'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (5,20): Cannot find module './tools/config'. (2307)
gulpfile.ts (6,47): Cannot find module './tools/utils'. (2307)
```

It worked well before I made  'npm install' on clean repo. Now I receive this error and I have no idea whats wrong. Two days ago, it worked without a problem.

Please help.

**Gulpfile.ts** (it was not changed since last successful build):

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as util from 'gulp-util';
import * as runSequence from 'run-sequence';

import Config from './tools/config';
import { loadTasks, loadCompositeTasks } from './tools/utils';


loadTasks(Config.SEED_TASKS_DIR);
loadTasks(Config.PROJECT_TASKS_DIR);

loadCompositeTasks(Config.SEED_COMPOSITE_TASKS, Config.PROJECT_COMPOSITE_TASKS);


// --------------
// Clean dev/coverage that will only run once
// this prevents karma watchers from being broken when directories are deleted
let firstRun = true;
gulp.task('clean.once', (done: any) => {
  if (firstRun) {
    firstRun = false;
    runSequence('check.tools', 'clean.dev', 'clean.coverage', done);
  } else {
    util.log('Skipping clean on rebuild');
    done();
  }
});
```

**EDIT 1**
*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Modular starter project for Angular 2 (and beyond) with statically typed build and AoT compilation",
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build.dev": "gulp build.dev --color --env-config dev",
    "build.dev.watch": "gulp build.dev.watch --color",
    "build.e2e": "gulp build.e2e --color",
    "build.prod": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.prod.exp": "gulp build.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.prod.rollup.aot": "gulp build.prod.rollup.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.prod.aot": "gulp build.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.test": "gulp build.test --color",
    "test.watch": "gulp test.watch --color",
    "generate.manifest": "gulp generate.manifest --color",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e.live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n -p src/client/tsconfig.json && gulp clean.i18n",
    "lint": "gulp tslint",
    "karma": "karma",
    "karma.start": "karma start",
    "postinstall": "gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner",
    "reinstall": "npm cache clean && npm install",
    "serve.coverage": "gulp serve.coverage --color",
    "serve.dev": "gulp serve.dev --color --env-config dev",
    "serve.e2e": "gulp serve.e2e --color",
    "serve.prod": "gulp serve.prod --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "serve.prod.aot": "gulp serve.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "serve.prod.exp": "gulp serve.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "serve.prod.rollup.aot": "gulp serve.prod.rollup.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "start": "gulp serve.dev --color",
    "start.deving": "gulp start.deving --color",
    "tasks.list": "gulp --tasks-simple --color",
    "test": "gulp test --color",
    "e2e.ci": "gulp build.prod --color && gulp build.e2e --color && gulp e2e --color",
    "tests.all": "npm test && npm run e2e.ci",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver-update": "node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update",
    "compodoc": "node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/client/tsconfig.json",
    "serve.compodoc": "node_modules/.bin/compodoc -s"
  },
  "author": "Minko Gechev <mgechev>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/async": "^2.0.32",
    "@types/browser-sync": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.33",
    "@types/gulp": "^3.8.32",
    "@types/gulp-filter": "^3.0.29",
    "@types/gulp-load-plugins": "^0.0.28",
    "@types/gulp-protractor": "^1.0.29",
    "@types/gulp-sass": "^0.0.29",
    "@types/gulp-util": "^3.0.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/rimraf": "0.0.28",
    "@types/run-sequence": "^0.0.28",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.39",
    "@types/systemjs": "^0.19.31",
    "@types/yargs": "^6.5.0",
    "@types/zone.js": "^0.0.27",
    "async": "^2.1.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.17.3",
    "codelyzer": "^2.1.1",
    "compodoc": "^0.0.40",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.7.7",
    "deep-extend": "^0.4.1",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.4",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "express-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp-progeny": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-template": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "7.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.10",
    "is-ci": "^1.0.9",
    "isstream": "^0.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "~1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.3",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "protractor": "^4.0.14",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.8.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "rollup": "^0.41.4",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.1",
    "rollup-plugin-includepaths": "0.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.1",
    "slash": "~1.0.0",
    "supports-color": "^3.1.2",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.15.34",
    "tildify": "^1.2.0",
    "traceur": "^0.0.111",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "walk": "^2.3.9",
    "yargs": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "1.11.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.1.3",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.12.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "2.0.1",
    "ngx-uploader": "^2.2.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the package.json? And what versions of npm and Node.js are you using?

Comment: @E_net4 see edit 1 plz.  Npm version: 5.0.4